# Does destroying SAM sites persist throughout the game?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I was just shot down from a SAM site that I thought I already destroyed with C4.  Does destroying a SAM site persist through my game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At 164 votes at posting, [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GhostRecon/comments/5wj4u5/sam_sites_should_not_respawn_once_destroyed/) seems to imply that SAM sites respawn and that it's a nuisance.

> Why do SAM sites respawn after they're destroyed? This was infuriating to deal with in the Beta. Why can I destroy them if they just come right back again?

It appears the beta version of the game had this "issue" as well.

Comment: Kind of ridiculous that almost 2 years later they never saw the need to fix it. Seems like it was one of the most annoying things about the game (which I did otherwise find really fun).